# How to change the color of the label in the livechart? wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, livecharts

I am trying to create a bar chart with livechart following this example:

https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Labels
[Bar chart with black labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8o6V.png)

My problem is I can't change the color of the label in the top of the bar. they are white and they can not be seen.

How could I change the color of the labels as the above example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to change the color:

```
labelsExample.SeriesCollection.OfType<ColumnSeries>().ToList().FirstOrDefault().Foreground = Brushes.Green;
```

I am not sure why you are having this issue. Default color is black: I followed the example in the link and I created a user control and I installed the nuget DLL and by default, the color is black for the labels on the bars as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

After changing the color to green, the color becomes green as shown below:

[image: Screenshot showing green labels]